# Changing value based on url

Tags: javascript

When click on the button it changes the url (#), but it's also supposed to change the value on in the other white box on the left. But I have to click the button twice before it changes, for some reason.

It doesn't change the white box on the left, but when I click again it works.

```js
function hashtag() {
  var indexof = window.location.href.lastIndexOf('#');
  var url = window.location.href.substr(indexof);
  var selectindex = 0;
  
  if (url == "#alacarte") {
    selectindex = 0;
  } else if (url == "#alfabet") {
    selectindex = 1;
  } else if (url == "#eigen") {
    selectindex = 2;
  }
  return selectindex;
}

function UpdateDropdownCat() {
  var number = hashtag();
  inputField.value = dropdownArray[number].textContent;
  //document.querySelector("#MenuDrop a:nth-child(2)").click()
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is `dropdownArray`?

Comment: That white box has a dropdown when clicked

Comment: ` <form>
        <input class="chosen-value" type="text">
        <ul class="value-list">
          <li><a href=menu.html#alacarte>Pizza à la carte</a></li>
          <li><a href=menu.html#alfabet>Alfabet pizzas</a></li>
          <li><a href=menu.html#eigen>Eigen pizza</a></li>
          <li><a href=menu.html#burgers>Burgers</a></li>
 
     
        </ul>
      </form>`